# Is it possible to use a PHP class in AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I started to wonder that is it possible to create a class in PHP, for instance one containing a books title, author and publisher, and then using that class in AJAX?

To clarify. By using I meant that is it possible to access the variables in that class or even use the functions created in php, such as setters/getters.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a basic ajax call to a php page and go from there.

Comment: You can have javascript execute a php script via ajax, yes,

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use a class in response to an AJAX request. AJAX pages are a lot like normal pages: they can read `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays, and do anything you can do in PHP.

Comment: No, javascript cant access/use those functions/variables, you'll need a php script that does that for you.

Comment: AJAX is an http request performed in the background by a client-side system, e.g. Javascript in a browser. It can NOT directly execute PHP code. But you can trivially have your ajax run a php script that would invoke that class to do something.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is create a separate class file and a function that will trigger the methods of this class. 
With ajax you will send requests for that file functions and then it will call the method of the class you need.